# How to add a subtitle to a Product title in WooCommerce's product page?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using wordpress, theme Astra, and I have looked everywhere and the code's that other people have tried doesn't work for me. Please see photo--I just want a subtitle under the Product title on the product page and also on the shop page

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you've tried?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant html from your page, or even a link to the page? It's easier to help if I can examine the elements.

Comment: @bman70 this is the link to the shop page: https://www.off-norm.com/product-category/accessories/

Comment: @Bman70 and link to my single product page: https://www.off-norm.com/product/fuck-you-bracelet/

Comment: So you want to add subtitle text under "Threaded Bracelet?"

Comment: @Bman70 exactly!